# Connecting to Remote Windows Desktop

Tags: python-3.x

Need help.Wanted to know is there any module in Python which helps to connect to Remote windows and copies some text file, say vb file, and executes it and get the result test file back to source system which may be Unix (mostly) or windows. However, the destination is always remote windows desktop. 
  Earlier we used Winrm module and ran scripts on remote desktop. However, we got to know that some system does not have Winrm so need to change the tactic, tried searching but could not get any in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use module os 
and the os.popen() to use NET.exe service command or more advanced scripting tools like https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9029/Push-and-Run-NET-Code-on-Remote-Machine. At least on windows NT like systems.